# Zero conditional form

Tags: grammar, rules, syntactic-analysis, construction

Chatting with a colleague we came a cross a dilemma (as we are not English native), which of the following sentences are wrong? Why?

1. If I knew everything, I'd be a genius.
2. If I know everything, I'd be a genius.
3. if I know everything, I'm a genius.

The 2nd should be wrong, as with the present I should use either the future or the present, in fact the 3rd seems to me correct, in fact the rule is:

> The Zero Conditional is used for
>   actions that are always true when the
>   conditions are satisfied.

So to form this particular condition I use this form:

```
If + Present Simple, + Present Simple
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: afaik the first one is correct (like "if i were you i'd..."), however English is not my first language

Comment: I endorse Kosmonaut's answer; but I cannot work out what you mean by "The Zero Conditional".

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sentences 1 and 3 are both correct.

Sentence 1 is a [counterfactual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Counterfactual) conditional sentence, and sentence 3 is a [factual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Factual) conditional sentence.

**Factual:**

> In these constructions, the condition clause expresses a condition the truth of which is unverified.

**Counterfactual:**

> In these constructions, the condition clause expresses a condition that is known to be false, or presented as unlikely.

---

Sentence 2 is indeed wrong because it is mixing the two in an incompatible way.